# Extracting timeseries tables from string into dictionary

Tags: python, regex, string, time-series

I have a text file that contains several time series data that looks like this:

```
Elect Price 
(Jenkins 1989)

1960 6.64784
1961 6.95902
1962 6.8534
1963 6.95924
1964 6.77416
1965 6.96237
1966 6.94241
1967 6.50688
1968 5.72611
1969 5.45512
1970 5.2703
1971 5.75105
1972 5.26886
1973 5.06676
1975 6.14003
1976 5.44883
1977 6.49034
1978 7.17429
1979 7.87244
1980 9.20048
1981 7.35384
1982 6.44922
1983 5.44273
1984 4.3131
1985 5.27546
1986 4.99998
1987 5.78054
1988 5.65552

Hydro Electricity 
(Guyol 1969; Energy Information Administration 1995)

1958 5.74306e+009
1959 5.90702e+009
1960 6.40238e+009
1961 6.77396e+009
1962 7.12661e+009
1963 7.47073e+009
1964 7.72361e+009
1980 1.62e+010
1985 1.85e+010
1986 1.88e+010
1987 1.89e+010
1988 1.96e+010
1989 1.95e+010
1990 2.02e+010
1991 2.05e+010
1992 2.04e+010
1993 2.12e+010

Nuclear Electricity
(Guyol 1969; Energy Information Administration 1995)

1958 4.43664e+006
1959 1.34129e+007
1960 2.56183e+007
1961 4.09594e+007
1962 6.09336e+007
1963 1.09025e+008
1964 1.59522e+008
1980 6.40598e+009
1985 1.33e+010
1986 1.42e+010
1987 1.55e+010
1988 1.68e+010
1989 1.73e+010
1990 1.77e+010
1991 1.86e+010
1992 1.88e+010
1993 1.95e+010
```

I have it loaded up as a single string and I am wondering what the best way would be to convert it into a dictionary of the form:

```
{('Elect Price', '(Jenkins 1989)'): [(1960, 6.64784), (1961, 6.95902), (1962, 6.8534), ...], ...}
```

My first instinct is to go line by line through the string and check to see if a few different regular expressions match and go from there, but I'd also have to include logic to handle what to do after a variable name is matched, then the citation, and the data, etc.

Is there a better way to do this? Possibly with some kind of template to extract the variable name, citation, and data as mentioned? I'm sure this is a fairly common task so I'm assuming there are more standard methods/tools for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement the use of the built-in string method `split`. First split by two consecutive newlines. Then, iterate through the created list in batches of two to individually format the data, also implementing `split` to split by single newlines. The specific formatting should be easy but it will be tedious.

Perhaps something like this:

```
def parse_input(s):
    # split by two consecutive newlines
    s = s.split("\n\n")

    out = {}
    for i in range(0, len(s), 2):  # iterate in chunks of two.
        # split key by newline, remove extra spaces, and convert to tuple
        key = tuple(map(lambda x: x.strip(), s[i].split("\n")))
        # split value by newline, split each line by space, and evaluate  
        # each piece of data with the builtin 'eval' function.
        value = list(map(lambda x: tuple(map(eval, x.split())), s[i + 1].split("\n")))
        out[key] = value
    return out
```

Since I am new to *stackoverflow*, please tell me how to improve my answer.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why you've used the eval function here but I appreciate the answer. I ended up coming up with something that works but I'm still interested to see what others might come up with.

Comment: I just wanted to have an easy way to parse the data as an `int` for the first number but a `float` for the second.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a great website to help with parsing data stored in a similar format [here](https://www.vipinajayakumar.com/parsing-text-with-python/). What I was unsure of what how to use regex to parse multi-line data. I didn't formulate the question this way as I did not want to restrict it to this approach, but using this website here is what I came up with:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

rx_dict = {'data': re.compile(r'^(\d+)\s'),
           'citation': re.compile(r'^(?P<citation>\(.+\))'),
           'variable': re.compile(r'^(?P<variable>[\w|\d|\s]+)$')}


def _parse_line(line):
    """
    Do a regex search against all defined regexes and
    return the key and match result of the first matching regex

    """

    for key, rx in rx_dict.items():
        match = rx.search(line)
        if match:
            return key, match
    # if there are no matches
    return None, None


def parse_file(filepath):
    """
    Parse text at given filepath

    Parameters
    ----------
    filepath : str
        Filepath for file_object to be parsed

    Returns
    -------
    data : dict
        Parsed data

    """

    data = {}  # create an empty dict to collect the data
    # open the file and read through it line by line
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file_object:
        line = file_object.readline()
        while line:
            if not line.strip():
                line = file_object.readline()
            # at each line check for a match with a regex
            key, match = _parse_line(line)

            # extract variable name
            if key == 'variable':
                variable = match.group('variable').strip()

            # extract citation
            if key == 'citation':
                citation = match.group('citation').strip()

            # identify beginning of data
            if key == 'data':
                data[(variable, citation)] = [[], []]
                # read each line of the table until a blank line
                while line.strip():
                    # extract number and value
                    year = int(line.split(' ')[0])
                    value = float(line.split(' ')[1])

                    data[(variable, citation)][0].append(year)
                    data[(variable, citation)][1].append(value)

                    line = file_object.readline()

            line = file_object.readline()

    return data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    filepath = "data_txt.txt"

    data = parse_file(filepath)
```

This approach tests a set of regular expressions on each line of the string to find out whether it contains a variable name, citation, or data. Upon finding the data each line is read and processed until a blank line is found. This gives me something close to the desired result, except that I opted to store the data in a list of lists instead of a list of tuples.